# Which is correct "get" or "got" in this context?

Tags: verbs, tenses, past-tense

> You know what it feels like to be ignored and you **got** angry

[referring to a previous event in the past]

> You know what it feels like to be ignored and you **get** angry

[~it is not nice to be ignored, yet when X happens you get angry] - habitual/everytime

Are both got and get correct in the above context?

Comment: Neither. The parallel structures and their tenses have to match. "You know what it feels like to be ignored and [to] get angry", or "you know what it feels like when you're ignored and [you] get angry", or "you know what it felt like when you got ignored and [you got] angry". But not a mix of the three. That just does not work.

Comment: @RegDwigнt that’s an old wives tale... clauses and sentences only have to maintain the tense if they’re occurring at the same time: “*The tenses of verbs in a sentence must be consistent when the actions happen at the same time. When dealing with actions that occur at different points in time, however, we can – and probably should – use multiple tenses in the same sentence*”. But if what you say is true that means you can’t mix tenses in the same sentence which is **wrong**, otherwise sentences in English would be become very monotonous.

Comment: That rule wouldn’t allow:  [*“I **have bought** a bike because I **will be** without my car for a month”*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59168/is-it-allowed-to-mix-tenses-in-one-sentence). But it’s a perfectly valid sentence in English and goes unnoticed as odd.